Inject proxy creds to all network requests using Python or JS
I am trying to create an application which should Inject proxy credentials to all the network requests which I bought from nstproxy.com. I tried to route all the network request from all the ports to a single port so that I can later monitor and inject proxy headers to all those request headers.

let stopCommand;
let command;

if (platform === 'linux') {
    // Linux - Use iptables
    command = `
        iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080 &&
        iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
    `;

    // Linux - Remove iptables rules
    stopCommand = `
        iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080 &&
        iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
    `;

} else if (platform === 'darwin') {
    // macOS - Use pfctl (remove 'sudo' since we use sudoExec)
    command = `
        echo "rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080" | tee -a /etc/pf.conf &&
        pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf && pfctl -e
    `;

    // macOS - Disable pfctl
    stopCommand = 'pfctl -d';

} else if (platform === 'win32') {
    // Windows - Use netsh (use block instead of allow)
    command = `
        netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Proxy HTTP Redirect" protocol=TCP dir=out localport=80 action=block &&
        netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Proxy HTTPS Redirect" protocol=TCP dir=out localport=443 action=block
    `;

    // Windows - Remove netsh rules
    stopCommand = `
        netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Proxy HTTP Redirect" &&
        netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Proxy HTTPS Redirect"
    `;
}

// Check if the user wants to start the proxy or stop the proxy in the node terminal
if (process.argv[2] === 'start') {
    // Start proxy
    sudoExec(command, options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error executing command:', error);
        } else if (stderr) {
            console.error('Command stderr:', stderr);
        } else {
            console.log(`Command output: ${stdout}`);
            console.log('Proxy setup complete');
        }
    });

} else if (process.argv[2] === 'stop') {
    // Stop proxy
    sudoExec(stopCommand, options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error stopping proxy:', error);
        } else if (stderr) {
            console.error('Command stderr:', stderr);
        } else {
            console.log(`Proxy routing stopped. Output: ${stdout}`);
        }
    });
}


but this doesn't work(at least on Mac). I don't know if it's a good idea to do so! is there any other methods that I can use to inject proxy credentials to all the network headers so that all the requests would be forwarded via that proxy?
If this question or any part of this question sounds stupid, please remember I am not an experienced network engineer! I am not even a network engineer, I am just a student working as a Software development intern.

This is an HTTP proxy? There's a standardized header for that... and also error handling (407) that is returned if it fails... you should be looking at in your client's request log.
